# AngularJS deep filter through array in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

My question is looking similar to other questions. But it is different.
Please take a look of below code.

I want to filter data by an array of objects.

Here is the snippet

**HTML**

```
<div
ng-repeat="(key, value) in ledgerData.ledgers track by $index"
ledger-pop 
index="$index"
ftype="ftypeUpdate"
itemdata="value" 
acntlist="fltAccntList"
class='drEntryForm_{{$index}} pr'
name='drEntryForm_{{$index}}'
update-ledger="updateEntry(entry)"
novalidate
>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.ledgerDataata = {
      "ForwardedBalance": {
      "amount": 0,
      "type": "CREDIT"
      },
      "creditTotal": 4008,
      "debitTotal": 4008,
      "balance": {
      "amount": 4008,
      "type": "CREDIT"
      },
      "ledgers": [
            {
              "transactions": [
                {
                  "particular": {
                    "name": "Sarfaraz",
                    "uniqueName": "temp"
                  },
                  "amount": 1001,
                  "type": "DEBIT"
                }
              ],
              "description": "testing",
              "tag": "testing"
            },
            {
              "transactions": [
                {
                  "particular": {
                    "name": "frnd",
                    "uniqueName": "frndafafaf14453422453110l26ow"
                  },
                  "amount": 2001,
                  "type": "CREDIT"
                },
                {
                  "particular": {
                    "name": "Rahul",
                    "uniqueName": "cake"
                  },
                  "amount": 3001,
                  "type": "DEBIT"
                }
              ],
              "description": "testing",
              "tag": "testing",
            }
      ]
}
```

I am trying to filter by

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in ledgerData.ledgers track by $index | filter:{transactions[0]:{type: 'DEBIT'}}"
```

But am getting error

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to write nested ng-repeat to solve this problem.

- outer ng-repeat for the array ledgerData.ledgers and
- inner ng-repeat for transaction array in ledgerData.ledgers

  ```html
      <div ng-repeat="(keyOne, ledger) in ledgerData.ledgers track by $index">
                 {{ledger.description}}
           <div ng-repeat="(keyTwo, transaction) in ledger.transactions | filter:{type:'DEBIT'}">
                    {{transaction.type}} 
           </div>
      </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the solution.

I've googled hardly and got a library for `angularjs-filter`.

[Here is the link](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)  it is very good plugin for `filter dirty works` and how to use it.

How I got success:

**html**

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in ledgerData.ledgers | pick: debitOnly track by $index"
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.debitOnly = (ledger) ->
  'DEBIT' == ledger.transactions[0].type
```

that's it.